# When using Broadcast Stream in Flink，the broadcast state of different subtasks of the same operator is isolated or shared?

Tags: state, apache-flink, broadcast

In my flink job, i use Broadcast State like this:

```
env.setParallelism(4);
BroadcastStream<String> configBroadcastStream = env.addSource(new BroadCastDataSource(), "BroadCastDataSource").broadcast(configStateDescriptor);
DataStream<String> mapStream = withWatermarkStream.map(e -> e.f4);
DataStream<String> connectedStream = mapStream.connect(configBroadcastStream).process(new BroadcastFunction(configStateDescriptor));
```

i wonder that if the broadcast state accessed by different subtasks of the same operator(the code shows as below) is isolated?

```
BroadcastState<String,String> state = context.getBroadcastState(mapStateDescriptor);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each subtask maintains its own independent copy of the broadcast state. The working state is always on-heap (like all non-keyed state), and each subtask independently includes its copy of the broadcast state in checkpoints and savepoints. Using RocksDB for broadcast state is not an option.

Note that if the broadcast stream comes from a parallel source, different subtasks can receive the broadcast elements in a different order. You need to either restrict the broadcast source to a single instance, or take care that broadcast state updates do not depend on the order of their arrival, or you can end up with inconsistencies.

See [the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/broadcast_state.html#important-considerations) for more info.